# Cannot get the checked radio correctly in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Page code as below:

```
<input type="radio" class="direct" name="r1" value="first" />
    <span class="proxy">radio1</span>
<input type="radio" class="direct" name="r1" value="second" />
    <span class="proxy">radio2</span>
```

js code as below:

```
$('.direct').click(function(e) {
    var obj = $(this).parent(),
        value = obj.find('input:checked').val();
    if(value){
        alert('you click ' + value + ' button');
    }else{
        alert('you did not click a button');
    }
});
$('.proxy').click(function(e) {
    $(this).prev().click();
});​
```

Here is the [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yejinxin/c5sMA/)

My question is:
why clicking on span text does not work like clicking directly on radio button?

Comment: Can't you use a `label` element instead?

Comment: i'm not clear what you wanted to achieve. I see the radio is 'checked' when i click the corresponding span!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said earlier, question was not clear, at least for me. however, if you want to get the radio checked when clicked on next span, you can do this way:

```
$('.proxy').click(function(e) {
    $(this).prev().attr('checked', true)
});​
```

Comment: This will set the previous input's attribute as checked. In the user's question, the click event is triggered and does not set the previous input's attribute, and therefore his coding does not work.

Comment: Thanks. At last, I make it work by:`$('.proxy').click(function(e) {
    $(this).prev().attr('checked', true);
    $(this).prev().click();
});​`

Comment: @williamcarswell Yes, that's what I mean. Could you tell me why this happens

Comment: you can try shorter format of what you wrote. `$('.proxy').click(function(e) { $(this).prev().attr('checked', true).click(); });`

Comment: @yejinxin I am glad you found the solution. In basic terms, when you click on the radio button, the input radio field is set to a checked state, however, when you triggered the .click() event for the input radio, you did not set the attribute to a check state.

Comment: @williamcarswell Thanks, you're right. So I find another solution: use the "change" handler for radio instead of "click". Seems like that "change" event is automatically fired after .click(), but it's another case for user click.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a label with `for` attribute set to the correct input, you could avoid all this problem.

```
<input type="radio" class="direct" name="r1" id="r11" value="first"/>
<label class="proxy" for="r11">radio1</label>
<input type="radio" class="direct" name="r1" id="r12" value="second"/>
<label class="proxy" for="r12">radio1</label>​​​​​​​​​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FyUcW/)

Comment: that's true! but seems he wanted to get it done using jQuery! i'm wondering why! (at least for this scenario)

Comment: @HungryCoder well, it's because I'm maintaining other's code. If I change it to label way, I have to change a lot of code...